# Calling cache.addAll() with hundreds of URLs?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

how to add all urls if 100's of urls are there,  there is another method to add url if lot of urls are there

```
this.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/static/js/main.chunk.js',
                '/static/js/0.chunk.js',
                '/static/js/bundle.js',
                '/static/css/main.chunk.css',
                '/bootstrap.min.css',
                '/index.html',
                '/',
      ]);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is? `cache.addAll()` will let you pass in as many URLs as you want. Are you asking about how to generate the list of URLs programmatically, at build time? Are you asking about how to spread out the network requests so that they don't consume as much bandwidth during `install`? Or are you asking because some of the URLs might fail to cache, causing `install` to fail?

Comment: cache.addAll is way too unsafe to add lots of urls. It hangs... Not sure why... Currently looking for a solution...